# How to reference assemblies targeting higher framework in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a project that targets .Net 3.5 framework and I need to add a reference which is targeting 4.0. Is it possible to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. You'd have to change your framework target.

Comment: Are you able to just change the project target? That's the obvious approach.

Comment: Yes, I am able to change the project target to .Net 4.0. But I wanted to see if there is a way to avoid changing the target but apparently it  does not seem to be possible. Thanks everyone for your comments and clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLR v2.0 applications (including those targeting .Net framework 3.5) cannot see CLR v4.0 assemblies.
 See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727509.aspx) for an excellent explaination.

Answer (score 9):

That's not possible.

.Net 4.0 assemblies run against a newer version of the CLR.

Answer (score 2):

Only possible if you retarget your project to version 4 or higher. Project properties.