# Why are public types in one project not visible to other projects?

Tags: c#, .net, types, import

I have project **XTime.Sephaku.GenSync.Plugin** that translates SAP IDocs to our internal DB structure. It builds fine, and if I put it's classes into a Console app, that app runs fine, so the plugin code is fine.

I then have Console project **Tester**, with a reference to the output assembly from the plugin, **XTime.Sephaku.GenSync.Plugin***. It doesn't see any of the public types in the plugin, despite that assembly being freshly built, and the public types all visible in Object Browser. I have copy and pasted namespaces for `using` statements to make sure I don't have a typo. The namespaces and public types are also all visible in *dotPeek's* decompiled code.

It's like something is telling **XTime.Sephaku.GenSync.Plugin** to not allow other projects to use it's types.

*** See my [Why do I get a warning icon when I add a reference to an MEF plugin project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186216/why-do-i-get-a-warning-icon-when-i-add-a-reference-to-an-mef-plugin-project) for why I don't reference the project, but rather the assembly.

Comment: All classes that you are trying to access are public? not just the members, right? Remember that classes default to private if not set to public.

Comment: the assembly XTime.Sephaku.GenSync.Plugin in the console project "tester" can you open that assembly in ILDASM and show us the snapshot of it.

Comment: Could it be that the `Tester` project has a newer version of .NEt the referenced plugin?

Comment: @Jite Classes default to `internal` not `private`. FYI you can't make namespace members private or protected even if you specify explicitly.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you for the clarification, good to know. But it would still give the same issue, so the question stands! ;)

Comment: @Jite yep.. I agree with you.. It should be `public`..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes of course. A private class within a namespace, which could only be reached from itself would be quite useless!
It's 'package private' (omg java noo!!) ;P

Comment: All four classes in **XTime.Sephaku.GenSync.Plugin** are explicitly marked `public`. @Avi is correct in that the plugin is 4.5.1 and **Tester** only 4.5. Setting its version to 4.5.1 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

Your Tester project cannot have a higher version of .NET than the referenced plugin.
You need to make sure that the referencing project have a version of .Net that is equal or higher to the plugin's version.

you can red more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914796/how-to-reference-assemblies-targeting-higher-framework-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: The tester project, although added today, with VS 2013, had the *lower* version. I didn't even know there was a 4.5.1, which was the plugin version.